# Migrate AD DHCP to New Server: Some on old and others on new

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp, windows-server-2019

We used to have one AD box, AD1. We since added two new AD boxes: AD2 & AD3. The idea was to decommission the old box.

I went through DHCP Manager and set the scope and everything seems fine. Right click on DHCP and selecting "Manage authorized server" shows the new new boxes: AD2 and AD3.

I went to one workstation and did issued `ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew`. The box releases right away and more importantly renews right away and shows AD2 as the DHCP server.

I then went to another workstation but any attempts to "renew" without AD1 turned on and authorized yields no connection. I even turned the box off and then back on. When connected, it shows AD1 as the DHCP server, obviously.

I did see this [quesiton](https://serverfault.com/questions/703391/windows-dhcp-clients-randomly-revert-to-old-dns-servers). I went to the old DHCP and verified that the DNS server option in DHCP record points to the new box. I also verified the first option in the forward lookup zone that the new servers show up in the `Name Servers` and the `WINS` tabs.

I checked and both workstations have obtain an IP address automatically and DNS servers automatically in the IPV4 properties for the adapter. Going to the Ethernet adapter on the second machine going to the old server and seeing if that has the old server listed rather than obtain an IP address automatically was my first thought.

Why can this second workstation not see the new DHCP server: AD2 and how do I fix the problem? Is the problem something that needs setting on our switch? (just a thought)

**UPDATE:**

I found a key piece to the puzzle. We have 3 subnets

1. .70.*: Servers & Printers
2. .71.*: Workstations
3. .72.*: Phone

The workstation that works, when AD1 is off, gets an IP address on the 70 subnet, whereas the workstation that fails and requires AD1 has an IP address on the 71 subnet.

I also verified that when AD1 is off and I attempt to request an IP address, [Microsoft Packet Sniffer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-netmon) shows that the failing workstation can indeed talk on the network, as I see packets flying by.

I would say the problem is with the switch, and still might be a configuration on our main switch, however both the AD1 and AD2 have IP addresses on the 70 subnet.

JoeQuerty said that a missing DHCP Relay setting in our `Brocade ICX 6450-24P` smart switch (router) is the problem. A Google search turned up [this question](https://forums.ruckuswireless.com/ruckuswireless/topics/how-do-i-configure-an-ip-helper-for-dhcp-when-handling-mulitple-vlans), which says the same thing. As stated in my question, the only hesitation is that AD1 works and AD2 fails and both are on the 70 subnet and use the same switch with the current settings.

Comment: 1. The DHCP process is unrelated to DNS. 2. Was there a reservation for the PC in question in the DHCP scope on AD1? Run a packet capture on the PC and issue a release and renew. At the same time run a packet capture on AD1, AD2, and AD3. Then interrogate the captures, filter the captures for DHCP, and see what you see on the client and the servers.

Comment: Additionally, when migrating DHCP you can export and import the DHCP config using netsh or Powershell. This will ensure that you don't miss anything.

Comment: @joeqwerty no on the AD1 reservations. Someone else did the initial setup on AD2/3. I went back this morning and cleaned a few things up and eliminated all traces of AD1. I even picked a nice machine which was able to ipconfig /release /renew, just I found out that other workstations refuse to deal with any DHCP server that is not AD1. I will locate a packet sniffer. :-( I am not an expert in packet sniffing, so we shall see on that. I read up on DHCP config export/import this morning. That is not an issue or needed now.

Comment: @joeqwerty The packet sniffer, see update to my question, was helpful as I though that there would be no network traffic, but in fact there is network traffic. The problem is (details above) that the failing computer is on our .71 subnet, whereas the computer that works gets an IP address on the .70 subnet. That points to either a switch issue or more than likely a difference in the configuration between AD1 and AD2.

Comment: Assuming that you have a DHCP scope configured on AD2 for each subnet, then the problem is most likely with your router. The router needs to use the DHCP Relay function to know where to relay DHCP traffic from clients that are on subnets other than the subnet the server is on. Your switch might be performing this function if it's a Layer 3 switch.

Comment: Depending on what make/model your router is, look for settings related to DHCP Relay, DHCP Helper, or IP Helper.

Comment: @joeqwerty AD1, AD2, & AD3 each have the same scope for each subnet. I literally just checked that out. I went item to item. Joe, what I do not understand is that if the router say is not using DHCP Relay function for clients on the .71 subnet, then why can AD1 provide IP addresses, as both boxes are on the 70 subnet and attached to the same local switch. AD1, AD2, & AD3 sit inches from one another. The local stupid switch then goes up to our Brocade ICX6450-24P smart switches upstairs.

Comment: @joeqwerty I am reading up on Google and I believe that you are right. I will add a link to a QA that I am looking at.

Comment: The DHCP Relay Agent (where ever it is, most likely your router or Borcade switch) is configured to forward DHCP traffic from the other subnets to AD1. It needs to be configured to relay DHCP traffic to AD2 and Ad3.

Comment: @joeqwerty wow! I thought that DHCP Relay agents forward to a subnet not a specific box. I do not know why I thought that. What you said makes sense. I am an idiot for thinking the forward was to a subnet. Of course. Okay, I feel dumb. AD2/3 are new, so of course the Brocade switch would not know about that. Okay, I feel dumb now. Thank you.

Comment: You're not dumb at all. You can't know something until you work with it. None of us are born knowing this stuff. It's experience and knowledge gained. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DHCP server is on one subnet. You have DHCP clients on other subnets. In order for the DHCP traffic from these other subnets to reach the DHCP server you need a DHCP relay agent running on your router that will forward the DHCP traffic from those other subnets to your DHCP server.

Your DHCP relay agent is currently configured to forward DHCP traffic to AD1. You need to configure the DHCP relay agent to forward DHCP traffic to AD2 and AD3. Find where your DHCP relay agent is and reconfigure it. This will fix the problem.

These have been immensely helpful to me in my IT career:

[https://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Protocols-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321336313](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336313)

http://www.tcpipguide.com/

Comment: he still knows his stuff.  Hope things are well Joe.  +1

Comment: @TheCleaner  Long time! We're good here. Hope you and yours are well!

Comment: @joeqwerty Our switch person made a change and my failed PC now talks to AD3, though I am having them change to AD2. Bingo on answer.